# Rsyslog doesn't filter expression

Tags: docker, rsyslog

I want to filter every log message with the text 'JSD' in it, so I set up filter expression:
`:msg, contains, "JSD"    /var/log/docker/docker.log` in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`.

However, when this log message is generated, nothing goes to `/var/log/docker/docker.log` and the following log entry appears in the `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul 10 16:32:57 jsd-user-management rsyslogd: action 'action 0' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), 
next retry is Fri Jul 10 16:33:27 2020, retry nbr 0. There should be messages before this one giving the
 reason for suspension. [v8.32.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was running on `root`, so when I created the `/var/log/docker` directory, it took `root` permissions, but `syslog` user doesn't have `root` permissions.
Issue can be fixed by either providing write permissions to `/var/log/docker` or changing owner of the directory to `syslog`